# Azure Cosmos Query against Date By Range

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am querying data against one field where the datatype is Datetime for example my query looks like this,

```
Select * from c where c.datetime >= '19/04/2021' and c.datetime <= '23/04/2021'and c.age = 25
```

there is no issue while reading the data but it's taking too much time and RU's.

can someone suggest me or help me by giving me a example code to add the range or composite indexes in cosmos indexing policy for the above query.

Comment: what is the partitionKey

Comment: in that query partion key is not involved

Comment: @Sajeetharan is there any possibilities to fetch 50,000 records in one go in less than 30 seconds,(do we have any chance)

Comment: That looks like a use for composite indexing. Have you tried any variations based on docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a slow or high request unit (RU) query, you can optimize  it with a composite index. By default, no composite indexes are defined so you would have to add composite indexes as needed.

**Query:**

```
Select * from c where c.age = 25 and c.datetime >= '19/04/2021' and c.datetime <= '23/04/2021';
```

**Composite indexe:**

```
(age ASC, datetime ASC)
```

As explained in the MS doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#:%7E:text=ascending%20or%20descending%29.-,Note,-When%20you%20add):

> **Note:** When you add a composite index, the query will utilize existing range indexes until the new composite index addition is
> complete. Therefore, when you add a composite index, you may not
> immediately observe performance improvements. It is possible to track
> the progress of index transformation [by using one of the SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-indexing-policy).

For more details checkout : [Composite indexing policy examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-manage-indexing-policy?tabs=dotnetv2%2Cpythonv3#composite-index) and [Updating indexing policy using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-manage-indexing-policy?tabs=dotnetv2%2Cpythonv3#updating-indexing-policy)

```
{  
        "automatic":true,
        "indexingMode":"Consistent",
        "includedPaths":[  
            {  
                "path":"/*"
            }
        ],
        "excludedPaths":[],
        "compositeIndexes":[  
            [  
                {  
                    "path":"/age"
                },
                {  
                    "path":"/datetime"
                }
            ]
        ]
}
```

It is optional to specify the order. If not specified, the order is ascending.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Working with datetimes

> I am querying data against one field where the datatype is Datetime..

First of all, CosmosDB is a document storage for JSON documents. [JSON notation does NOT have a data type `DateTime`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). If you look at your query, you are actually passing strings. If you look at your stored documents, you are storing   strings. CosmosDB does not know nor care if they represent points in time in your app.

Hence the ordering of your datetimes in your query (and index) IS NOT chronological, but literal. Most likely you wanted the former, though.

**To make your strings with datetimes indexable as time, you must use a format in which the literal order and chronological order is the same. Usually ISO-8601.**

You should start by reading this for more details:
[Working with Dates in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/working-with-dates).

### About composite indexes

It heavily depends how you model your data, data distribution and optimization priorities, but...

... **usually a simpler and more universal single-path index is preferred** due to smaller index size and higher reusability. While you could add a lot of composite indexes to get small gains in specific queries, but each added index does bring a cost in index maintenance (inserts, updates, deletes) + dev maintenance + index storage. DO add only add indexes you actually use and test the RU cost before adding heavier indexes.

See also : [Performance tips for Azure Cosmos DB and .NET - Indexing policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3-sql#indexing-policy)